# Solicita N números, luego pregunta si desea sumarlos o restarlos (PYTHON)

Tags: python

Este fue un programa que me dejaron de tarea, no lo supe hacer, creo que sería con el ciclo `for`, pero aún necesito aprender mucho, Alguien me podría ayudar?

```
n = int(input("Cuanto numeros quieres:"))
n2 = int(input("Dame numeros:"))
opcion = 0
while True:
    print("""
        Dime, ¿qué quieres hacer?

        1) Sumar los dos números
        2) Restar los dos números
        """)
    opcion = int(input("Elige una opción: ") )

    if opcion == 1:
        print(" ")
        print("RESULTADO: La suma de",n1,"+",n2,"es igual a",n1+n2)
    elif opcion == 2:
        print(" ")
        print("RESULTADO: La resta de",n1,"-",n2,"es igual a",n1-n2)
```

Comment: Estimado Axel, acá no hacemos tareas,   a menos que se vea que lo hayas intentado y para eso tienes que colocar  parte de tu código y un ejemplo mínimo verificable.
Revisa el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio!

Comment: Gracias, de hecho si lo intente

Comment: @AxelOsiris según tu código no suma N números, únicamente estás sumando dos elementos. Además debes tener cuidado con la indentación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución debería verse de esta manera:

1. Función que suma los valores de una lista:

```
def sumar(valores):
    
    resultado = 0
    for valor in valores:
        resultado += valor
    return resultado
```

2. Función que resta los valores de la lista:

```
def restar(valores):
    
    #primer elemento de lista
    resultado = valores[0]
    #restar el siguiente elemento de lista
    for i in range(1,len(valores)):
        resultado -= valores[i]
    return resultado
```

3. Pedir cantidad de elementos a operar y guardarlos en la lista:

```
#pedir numero de elementos
n = int(input("Número de elementos: "))

#lista donde se guardan los valores
listaElem = []

#guardar elementos
for i in range(0, n):
    valor = int(input("Valor: "))
    #agregar elemento a la lista de valores
    listaElem.append(valor)
```

4. Pedir la elección del usuario y llamar la función correspondiente:

```
#menu para el usuario
print("Menú")
print("1. Sumar")
print("2. Restar")

opcion = input("Selecciona opcion: ")

if opcion == "1":
    resultado = sumar(listaElem)
    print("Resultado = " + str(resultado))
elif opcion == "2":
    resultado = restar(listaElem)
    print("Resultado = " + str(resultado))
```

Comment: Para sumar una lista basta con `sum(lista)`.

Comment: Para restar una lista basta `lista[0] - sum(lista[1:])`. Usar ciclos es propio de lenguajes primitivos.